# React - How to set element background color same as parent

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm creating a custom input element with tailwind css. the input has floating labels so when user types or focus on input the label shrinks exactly as material ui.

I want to set label's background same as parent. so if the parent's background is white or gray it should have the same background. but I'm not sure how to achieve it. any suggestions?

```
export const CustomSelect = ({ label }) => {
  const [shrinked, setShrink] = useState(false);

  const handleLeave = (e) => {
    if (!e.target.value.length) setShrink(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className='relative'>
      <input
        onFocus={() => setShrink(true)}
        onBlur={handleLeave}
        className='w-full bg-transparent border border-gray-400 rounded hover:border-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:border-2 focus:border-blue-800'
        style={{ padding: '18.5px 14px', height: '24px' }}
        type='text'
      />
      <label
        style={{
          transform: shrinked
            ? 'translate(4px, -13px) scale(0.75)'
            : 'translate(12px, 7px) scale(1)',
          background: 'inherit',
        }}
        className={`${
          shrinked && 'text-blue-800'
        } absolute top-0 left-0 px-1 text-gray-500 transition pointer-events-none`}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You'd create a class with that colour in your parent and re-use it in your child component.

Comment: You can create a class related to background. Assign it to the parent element and then pass it as a prop to child element and then you can use the same class for child as well

Comment: I think this can be solved in two ways. As I see your input has a `bg-transparent` class which means it's background is transparent so you can get the `bg-transparent` to the label too. Or you can use a ref for the parent element and use `const color = theParentRef.current.backgroundColor;` and the set to your label's background in the `style` attribute or simply the same class with the css color attribute set for both, but as you are using tailwind i recommend the first way.

Comment: @RyanLe yeah, that could be a way to solve this. but I would like to do it without passing the color to input. if you look at material ui's outlined text input they're picking it automatically somehow. https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#textfield

Comment: @AlieAbbasi the label background is already transparent. there's no need to assign a class for it. I like your second approach. looking for a way without passing the color or refs. take a look at material ui's outlined text input https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#textfield

Comment: @vajad57 I guess you can access the label parent element with `theLabelElementRef.parentElement` then store its `style.bachgroundColor` into a variable and set the `label.backgroundColor` with that stored varibale.

Comment: good idea thanks :)